# Can't edit or comment on my own question

Tags: bug, comments, edits

I'm unable to edit or comment on my own question, which was migrated from English Language Learners to Japanese Language & Usage.

[image: Screenshot, describd below]

The "edit" link is greyed out, and there's no "Add comment" link for the question (but there is for one of the answers).

If this is deliberate, it needs to have better documentation.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/11556/revisions - the post is locked (due to rejected migration because of the close). Something weird might have happened though, a lock notice should appear I think.

Comment: Well, behavior seems consistent (e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191717/is-it-possible-to-license-wordpress-drupal-plugin-module-under-gpl-terms-when-pl is in the same state: locked without a notice, but comment box available on the answer. No edit links anywhere.) Comment thing is probably a bug, and could indeed be better documented.